# Cocos2D CCScene black screen, nothing happening?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have been trying to upgrade for the past 3 days from Cocos2D **1.1.0-pre->2.0rc0a** however this is the hardest task I have ever faced in making my app so far. So pretty much it worked fine in Cocos2D 1.1, my images loaded, everything worked, etc... Now in **2.0rc0a** it just goes to a black screen YET all of my methods are called!

Here is some information on the code I am using, devices, logs, etc...

***Xcode Version***

```
1. Xcode version: 4.3.2
```

***Devices tested on***

```
2. A) Devices: iPhone 4S - 5.0.1 (doesn't work)
B) iPad 3 - 5.1 (doesn't work)
C) iPhone 5.1 simulator (doesn't work)
D) iPad 5.1 simulator (doesn't work)
```

***My Code***

I have a UIViewController class which holds the CCGLView. I then have a CCLayer class which is everything for the actual game. The code in the CCLayer class is fine because it works in Cocos2D 1.1.0-pre so I will post the code for the UIViewController class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create an CCGLView with a RGB565 color buffer, and a depth buffer of 0-bits
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[self.view bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];
    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    [director_ setDisplayStats:YES];
    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    [director_ setView:glView];
    [director_ setDelegate:self];
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
    [director_ setDepthTest:FALSE];
    if(![director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES])
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
    [CCFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"@2x"];
    [CCFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-72"];
    [CCFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"@2x~ipad"];
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];
    [director_ pushScene:[CCSceneGame scene]];
}
```

Then I have this basic CCScene method in my CCLayer class:

```
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    CCSceneGame *layer = [CCSceneGame node];
    [scene addChild:layer];
    return scene;
}
```

Most of that code is copied directly from the template projects too. Also I have the delegates declared in the .h's.

***Console Output***

This is the console from me testing on my 5.0.1 iPhone 4S:

```
2012-03-31 17:14:54.484 App[56089:707] cocos2d: OS version: 5.0.1 (0x05000100)
2012-03-31 17:14:54.485 App[56089:707] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Imagination Technologies
2012-03-31 17:14:54.486 App[56089:707] cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: PowerVR SGX 543
2012-03-31 17:14:54.486 App[56089:707] cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES 2.0 IMGSGX543-63.14.2
2012-03-31 17:14:54.488 App[56089:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
2012-03-31 17:14:54.488 App[56089:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
2012-03-31 17:14:54.489 App[56089:707] cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
2012-03-31 17:14:54.489 App[56089:707] cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
2012-03-31 17:14:54.490 App[56089:707] cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
2012-03-31 17:14:54.490 App[56089:707] cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
2012-03-31 17:14:54.491 App[56089:707] cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
2012-03-31 17:14:54.491 App[56089:707] cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
2012-03-31 17:14:54.492 App[56089:707] cocos2d: cocos2d v2.0.0-rc0
2012-03-31 17:14:54.493 App[56089:707] cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
2012-03-31 17:14:54.745 App[56089:707] cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGBA888 texture since image has no alpha
2012-03-31 17:14:54.891 App[56089:707] cocos2d: CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. cgImage is nil
2012-03-31 17:14:54.892 App[56089:707] cocos2d: Couldn't add image:particleTexture.png in CCTextureCache
2012-03-31 17:14:54.999 App[56089:707] cocos2d: animation started with frame interval: 60.00
```

***A few other points***

1. My app is all UIKit except for this view
2. I show the UIViewController where the CCGLView is by doing [self addSubview:]; if that makes any difference
3. I have imported Cocos2D successfully to the point where I have no red files, no warnings, no errors, no deprecated API's etc...
4. My images have been modified so it has the suffixes I changed the CCFileUtils to in code. So it is: @2x, -72, and @2x~ipad
5. I also checked interface builder for any weird things going on and there are none

If anyone has any idea what is going on please let me know!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although everything @LearnCocos2D was true. The true fix for me was declaring a IBOutlet CCGLView in the .h and connecting it via Interface Builder.

I think there may be an issue if you use older projects and then upgrade to Cocos2D for some odd reason.

So instead of doing it programmatically, just do it via Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

I keep repeating myself, but alas:

If you need to update cocos2d in an existing project, the single most important thing is to **delete** all of the cocos2d files from the Xcode project and Finder. Then move the new cocos2d version in place, and re-add it.

Otherwise you may end up still having old cocos2d files in your project, or missing newly added files.

If the screen stays black this may indicate an issue with the shaders. The new cocos2d version has all the shaders as strings in header (.h) files. If you did not add those, they will not be working. Not sure if this will give you a black screen or crash outright.

Finally, since Cocos2D 2.0 uses OpenGL ES 2.0 you will have to rewrite all custom OpenGL drawing code that you have in your project.

Other things you should verify is that glView is not nil, and maybe set a breakpoint in CCDirector's update (visit/draw) method to check if it is actually visiting all nodes and drawing them correctly.

Comment: Ok I must have re-added and re-checked every file at least 3 times. Nothing is wrong. I am copying it directly from the way the template projects are. The header search paths are correct, everything is the 2.0rc0a version. I have cleaned it etc... No warnings or errors. Nothing is deprecated. My CCGLView is NOT nil neither is my director. Also my init method in my CCLayer gets called and no luck. I even tried putting the CCGLView into a UIView that I can clearly see, no luck, just a blank UIView. All of my shaders are there, no red files. And I don't have any deprecated OpenGL drawing code. ??